# Can I use my own model as a type of elements in arrays which are under a store

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I have 2 models: Noise and Radar and now I need a store to hold them in a way:

The store I call : DataBufferStore. Relations between them:

One DataBufferStore has 6 arrays called:

Noises, Radars, PreviousNoises, PreviousRadars, PPNoises, PPRadars.

PP means even before previous -> Previous previous.

So I'd like to call the DataBufferStore in order to get these 6 arrays of data in a way similar to:
DataBufferStore.Noises[X]
DataBufferStore.PrevousNoises[Y]
DataBufferStore.PPNoises[Z]

DataBufferStore.Radars[X]
DataBufferStore.PrevousRadars[Y]
DataBufferStore.PPRadars[Z]

These 6 arrays are arrays of Noise model and Radar model.

Can I do it this way below?

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.DataBuffer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'datetime', type: 'date' }
        ],
        associations: [
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'myApp.model.radar', name: 'Radars' },
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'myApp.model.Noise', name: 'Noises' },
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'myApp.model.radar', name: 'PreviousRadars' },
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'myApp.model.Noise', name: 'PreviousNoises' },
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'myApp.model.radar', name: 'PPRadars' },
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'myApp.model.Noise', name: 'PPNoises' }
        ]
    }
});
```

Comment: Why not just leave them as arrays? Specify `Radars` as a field on the model, don't specify a type.

Comment: hi @EvanTrimboli then how to write the code? could you please write me an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can.

As it is written in the [Documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.association.HasMany), you can create a store linked to your models (which is the same as an array), and associate it to your model.

```
Ext.define('Product', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',      type: 'int'},
            {name: 'user_id', type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name',    type: 'string'}
        ]
    }
});

Ext.define('User', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            {name: 'id',   type: 'int'},
            {name: 'name', type: 'string'}
        ],
        // we can use the hasMany shortcut on the model to create a hasMany association
        hasMany: {model: 'Product', name: 'products'}
    }
});
```

This allows you to use the store methods, some of them bieng pretty usefull.
To access the stores (or arrays as you call it) you can do it like that :

```
var products = user.products();
```

And then use this `var` to access your elements.

I **strongly** recommend to read the documentation for more information about that.

PS: If your 'PreviousRadars' is linked to your 'Radars', you can even nest the associations and put one in the Radar model which links to the Radar model, and call it PreviousRadar. That way you can have as many layers of Previous as you want.

EDIT: Explain the PS part :
Your databuffer only has the original radar and noises :

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.DataBuffer', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'datetime', type: 'date' }
        ],
        associations: [
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'Radar', name: 'Radars' },
            { type: 'hasMany', model: 'Noise', name: 'Noises' },
        ]
    }
});
```

Your radar (or noise) has an association with itself :

```
Ext.define('myApp.model.Radar', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: [
            { name: 'radarName', type: 'string' }
        ],
        associations: [
            { type: 'hasOne', model: 'Radar', name: 'previousRadar' },
        ]
    }
});
```

That way, you have the link between a radar and the previous one directly inside. If you have many previous radar for one radar, you can use `hasMany` instead.

I suggest you look [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-method-addListener) for your question about listeners (this is for listeners in store, but you can do the same for every object implementing the Observable interface).
You can find the events that can be listened at [here](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-event-addrecords). The `addrecords` is probably the one you are looking for.

Comment: Hi Saffron, thank you for your reply. The PS part of your post is more desirable, could you please explain it with a code sample? Also, how to write a "listener" which will be triggered when the data inside the store changed?

Comment: I added more detail about the PS, and some links for the listeners.

Comment: Hi Saffron, I am back to this project. Do you know how to initialize this model?

Comment: Just like any models. If you want to access the association, look at the documentation about this association. hasMany is accessing a store with a function (myradar.products() in the answer), hasOne is a simple myradar.getRadar() or mynoise.getNoise().